# Loomis and Sternberg Problem 4.1

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Problem 4.1 involves proving the following claim:

> If B is an affine subspace of  W and T ∈ Hom(V, W), then T⁻¹[B] is either empty or an affine subspace of V.

B being an affine subspace means that B = a + A = {a + v: v ∈ A}, where a ∈ W and A is a subspace of W.

Supposing T⁻¹[B] is not empty, I have conjectured that T⁻¹[B] = x + T⁻¹[A] (where x = a + k ∈ T⁻¹[B]), which would prove the claim, but I can't seem to prove this identity, as I am having issues dealing with inverses, for T may not be injective.

I know this question has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560037/preimage-of-an-affine-subspace?rq=1), but I don't quite understand the given answer (in particular, I don't know what is meant by an associated map.)

At this point, I'd like to see a full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we work over field $F$.  [Probably L&S work over $\mathbb R$?]
Let $u,v \in T^{-1}[B]$ and $\lambda \in F$.  The we must show $\lambda u + (1-\lambda) v \in T^{-1}[B]$.  [This is what it means to be an affine subspace.]
Our hypothesis $u,v \in T^{-1}[B]$ means $T(u), T(v) \in B$.  But
$$
T(\lambda u + (1-\lambda) v) = \lambda T(u)+(1-\lambda)T(v) .
$$
Now we know $T(u), T(v) \in B$ and $B$ is an affine space, so
$\lambda T(u)+(1-\lambda)T(v) \in B$.
[I'm guessing that $T \in \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ means $T$ is linear.  But the argument works if we merely assume $T$ is affine.]
Therefore
$T(\lambda u + (1-\lambda) v) \in B$ and thus
$\lambda u + (1-\lambda) v \in T^{-1}[B]$.

Comment: Hello. Have you a link where I can learn more about this characterization of affine subspace (in terms of "affine combination") ? The definition I know is the one used by the author in his question. Thank you.

Comment: @coboy I've found a post about the equivalence of these two definitions of affine subspaces: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240769/are-these-two-definitions-of-an-affine-subspace-equivalent

Comment: @112114116118 Thank you !